# How to chain multiple functions?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to chain a few functions in Clojure:

```
(f4 (f3 (f2 (f1 foo))))
```

Is there any convenient syntax sugar for this? Something like:

```
(with-all-of-them foo f1 f2 f3 f4)
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918554/can-clojure-evaluate-a-chain-of-mixed-arity-functions-and-return-a-partial-funct and see if that helps you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `->` macro.

```
(-> foo f1 f2 f3 f4)
```

Or `reduce`:

```
(reduce #(%2 %1) foo [f1 f2 f3 f4])
```

Comment: @vemv I think the `->` is cute. The `reduce` option clearly shows the operational pattern, and, unlike the threading macro, is happy to take on a sequence unknown at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [threading macro `->`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E):

```
(-> foo f1 f2 f3 f4)
```

Comment: Next to Figwheel this is seriously the most awesome thing I have seen today.

Answer (score 5):

Actually your description of `with-all-of-them` is very close to `comp`, except that `comp` returns a function that you must call yourself:

`(f4 (f3 (f2 (f1 foo))))` == `((comp f4 f3 f2 f1) foo)`

So, `with-all-of-them` could be implemented as follows:

```
(defn with-all-of-them [arg & fs]
   ((apply comp fs) arg))
```